# How to pass DSN to cfcomponent datasource property

Tags: coldfusion, railo

What is the best practice for passing application-scoped DSN value to a component?  Is it as follows?

```
component datasource="#application.dsn#"
```

I have always thought that it's not a good practice to use application-scoped variables inside components.  Would it be better like this?

```
component{
    function init( dsn, arg1, arg2 ){
          this.datasource = arguments.dsn;
   }
}
```

Comment: @cfvonner has answered this the way I would, but I'll make another coupla observations: you should be storing the DSN in `variables.datasource` not `this.datasource`. The this scope us for exposing values from within the component to the outside world, which is not what you're wanting to do here. Also I'd perhaps look at using a DI framework (DI/1, Wirebox) to handle your dependencies for you. But this depends on how complex your application is. It's worth at least *looking* at them though.

Comment: Good call Adam. I didn't catch the use of `this.datasource`.

Comment: I have a similar question to what @user2943775 asks, but my component is a webservice. I have done what is described in the answer here but given that my init method I've set as access="remote" seems to mean variables.dsn is not visible to other remote methods in the same component.  Maybe my init should not be remote? Private perhaps? Not sure. Any suggestions on getting the DSN into a webservice component with remote methods?

Answer (score 6):

Best practice is to keep components completely isolated from knowing anything about the outside world (including any variables external to a component, such as the application scope). You should pass in via arguments any data a component needs to fulfill it's intended purpose. So, based on that premise, your second code sample is the preferred approach.

Comment: Are you suggesting that every `<cfquery>` inside of a cfc should have its data source explicitly passed in and used?

Comment: What about setting the datasource in application.cfc and not explicitly passing it to the component?  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Setting the default datasource (in Application.cfc) is what you should be doing in any application that will not have multiple datasources - explicitly passing it around is just noise.

Comment: My philosophy is to not use variables for things that don't vary.  I see nothing wrong with simply hard coding datasource names into the cfquery tag, whereever it may be.

Comment: Hard coding things, like datasource names in `cfquery` tags is a terrible idea. Like Peter points out, the better approach is to set a default datasource in Application.cfc.

Comment: But if we use datasource in Application.cfc, the component is no longer independent and isolated from application scope?

Comment: There are different types of cfc's.  Some of them are designed to be available to more than one coldfusion application.  Those are the ones that really have to be isolated.  Those are also the ones where you are least likely to be passing datasource names as an argument.

Comment: Even if you define application.dsn, when you instantiate a component, you should always pass in the DSN (when needed) as an argument of its init() method. FWIW, application.dsn can be either a string or a struct, depending on how many data sources your application uses.

Comment: Also, if I understand it correctly, when you define an application datasource as `this.datasource` in Application.cfc, it's not put in the application scope (like specifying `this.mappings` doesn't create a "mappings" variable in application scope). And ColdFusion will "inject" the datasource into query tags/functions when the datasource argument is omitted.

Comment: @Carl, you are right, but the component would still be dependent on having that datasource be set in Application.cfc.  Just wondering, from a purist point of view whether this is the right practice.

Comment: @user2943775, yes, the component is dependent on datasource being set in Application.cfc. But the datasource is still being passed in, rather than the component "reaching" outside itself to get the datasource. It's just a kind of implicit dependency injection, really. I don't think it violates the principles of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

@cfvonner has replied in detail and is the correct answer, I believe. ColdFusion most of times allow you to do things as you want, use DSN as session, application, request, hardcoded too. But this flexibility should not an excuse for writing poor code. And as the question itself strive for "Good Practice" and your 2nd block of code does it rightly except the point @Adam Cameron raised. In short
 OOPs--->ENCAPSULATION--->Passing through parameter